# Is it possible to center a tkinter.simpledialog window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm including a conditional password capture in a larger script.  The code looks like this:

```
if thing:  # found token, don't need password
    do stuff
else:  # no token, get password in popup
    try:
        import tkinter as tk
        import tkinter.simpledialog
        tk.Tk().withdraw()
        passwd = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter password:", show="*")
        return passwd
```

functionally it's fine, but most of my users are on monitors at 3840x1600 resolution, so when the dialog pops up at the top left it's easy to miss.

Is there a brief way to override the simpledialog class to tell it to appear at a certain X/Y on the monitor, or is my only option to build a full `mainloop()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so when the dialog pops up at the top left it's easy to miss.

If you specify the optional argument *parent*, the dialogbox will appear in the middle of your window and gets the focus internally. Make sure your window is mapped via `.update_idletasks()` to get corresponding coordinates. You may consider also to make your window transparent instead of withdraw.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

def ask_pw():
    pw = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password",
                                        "Enter password:",
                                        show="*",
                                        parent=root)
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('250x250+500+500')
root.update_idletasks()
ask_pw()
#root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Low friction, brief, exactly what I was looking for, for a fallback to catch a password.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As the dialog is placed relative to the position of its parent, so you can center its parent, i.e. root window in your case:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()
# center root window
root.tk.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {root._w} center')
root.withdraw()

# set parent=root
passwd = simpledialog.askstring('Password', 'Enter password:', show='*', parent=root)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to override any of the classes to directly modify the underlying `_QueryString` class (also it is private so I didn't want to use that and I probably wouldn't have found an easy way with that anyways). So I just wrote a custom `askstring` function. The functionality is such that you need to provide the parent and the geometry and it will first schedule an inner function (could be a proper outer one but it should be fine) to get the last widget in the widgets of that parent and after the scheduled time it should be the new dialog so it should get that. (Check in place to check if that widget is derived from `dialog.Dialog` which is from what the `_QueryString` inherits). Then just change the geometry (because up the inheritance chain there is `Toplevel` which obviously has a `geometry` method):

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as dialog


def askstring(title, prompt, geometry='', **kwargs):
    def change_geometry():
        if not geometry:
            return
        widget = kwargs['parent'].winfo_children()[-1]
        if isinstance(widget, dialog.Dialog):
            widget.geometry(geometry)

    if 'parent' in kwargs:
        kwargs['parent'].after(10, change_geometry)
    return dialog.askstring(title, prompt, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

askstring('Title', 'Prompt', geometry='300x200+200+200', parent=root)
```

Useful:

- [source code for `tkinter.simpledialog`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py) which is what I used to solve this (also from previous experience)

Comment: You may are intrested in [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200429172751id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm). Sadly effbot isnt available these days.

Comment: @Atlas435 thanks for the link, I had missed that it sets its geometry based on the parent (didn't even read the code for it this time, went straight to inheritance and immediately failed because it is not possible to inherit from an object that is overriden later by the same object) and tried to find some other solution, however if geometry has to be set not based on parent's location or a larger size then this would have to be used, or just create a custom one using `Dialog`

Comment: yes I like your work around, its creatifly good. Thats why I upvoted this answer as well. A costum Dialog is even a bit trickier to do, you will notice if you try to imitated the return effect.

Comment: @Atlas435 I think at that point it would be much simpler to just copy-paste the `_QueryString` class add the geometry argument and then also copy the `askstring` function (just copy-paste into your code from source) and you are set. (could also inherit but as mentioned in my answer it is a private class)